# Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: 16.04, networking, bash, scripts, network-manager

I am Running Ubuntu 16.04 KDE. See this for specifications.

```
$ uname -a
  Linux ElMaverick 4.4.0-112-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 11:48:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/issue
  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

After every suspend, When I wake up my laptop, it never connects to any network and have to restart NetworkManager again. So, out of laziness I wrote this [script](https://ghostbin.com/paste/zo8ja) that worked very well.

I then edited my script as [suggested by muru here](https://askubuntu.com/a/997257/769206) in an answer to  question asked 2 weeks ago. When I executed this script, It shows me this error

```
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output of commands suggested in error is as follows :

#### systemctl status NetworkManager.service

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-01-29 10:00:51 IST; 14s ago
  Process: 25388 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Main PID: 25388 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

  Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
  Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Unit entered failed state.
  Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
  Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
  Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
  Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
  Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
```

#### journalctl -xe

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager.service has finished shutting down.
Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager.service has begun starting up.
Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick NetworkManager[25388]: NetworkManager is already running (pid 20138)
Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager.service has finished shutting down.
Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 29 10:00:51 ElMaverick systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
lines 1356-1393/1393 (END)
```

[This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862285/etc-init-d-networking-start-the-control-process-exited-with-error-code-see) is somewhat similar, but unfortunately it's unanswered.

[Similar Question here](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/error-systemctl-restart-network.345299/) suggests changing a parameter in the file

**`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`** from `BOOTPROTO=dhcp` to `BOOTPROTO=none`.

But I was unable to find that file on my system. So, I tried this in Root directory

```
$ ls -R | grep -i "BOOTPROTO"
```

That returned nothing.

As suggested in the [comment by muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000860/job-for-networkmanager-service-failed-because-the-control-process-exited-with-er?noredirect=1#comment1618389_1000860), click [this](https://ghostbin.com/paste/ckd48) to see output commands. I didn't write down here as they are too long.

1. Can anyone tell What is exactly going on and how to solve this ?
2. Also what change in [this](https://ghostbin.com/paste/zo8ja) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/997257/769206) script caused this error ?

Comment: It looks like there's a NetworkManager process that is running outside of the systemd service ("NetworkManager[25388]: NetworkManager is already running (pid 20138"). After you restart, before you restart NetworkManager, run `pgrep NetworkManager` and use the PID in the output to run `systemctl status <PID>`. Add the output in the question, please. Also, which version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: @muru edited question as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I had facing the same problem, than I try run this command:

```
sudo snap install hello-world
```

and start process snapd.seeded.service again:

```
systemctl start snapd.seeded.service
```

After that you can verify if `snmp.seeded.service` running smoothly:

```
$ systemctl status snapd.seeded.service
● snapd.seeded.service - Wait until snapd is fully seeded
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.seeded.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since xxx 2018-xx-xx xx:12:xx xxx; xxx ago
  Process: 26925 ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap wait system seed.loaded (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 26925 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

xxx xx xx:xx:xx xxx systemd[1]: Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
xxx xx xx:xx:xx xxx systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
xxx xx xx:xx:xx xxx systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
```

Comment: this link is very helpful :D 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042671/snapd-seeded-service-couldnt-start-on-upgrade

Comment: I don't get it. How installing `hello-world` snap program fixes this `NetworkManager` issue ?  Please add an explanation for the same.